# Testing Promise handling in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jasmine

In the source code I'm doing some processing on a Promise's successful resolve:

```
function saveChanges() {
  this.AppsSdkResource_
      .write(appssdkPackagePublishDetails)
      .then(
          function(response) {
            ... some processing ...
          }.bind(this));
}
```

In the test I set the mock behaviour for "writePackagePublishDetails" as below:

```
  var createSpyReturningPromise = function($q, name) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy(name).and.returnValue(defer.promise);
    spy.defer = defer;
    return spy;
  };
  appResource.write = createSpyReturningPromise($q, 'write');
  appResource.write.defer.resolve(
    dummyResponse);
  ctrl.saveChanges({$valid: true}); // Test the method of interest.
  mockClock.tick();
  .. do assertions for the "then" processing ...
```

But I find that the "then" code in the source file doesn't execute in resposne to mockClock.tick() and the test code after this statement gets executed first before the "then" code in the source file gets called.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do

```
scope.$digest();
done();
```

for promises to get resolved.